# Como saber la posición de un elemento que fue clickeado GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

resulta que estoy desarrollando una especie de bejeweled/candy crush y como en el juego original dispongo de un tablero de 8x8 (GridLayout) con 64 ImageViews, cada ImageView tiene lo siguiente

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:onClick="gemas"
    >
</ImageView>
```

Luego tengo una matriz de 8x8, en la cual almaceno en cada posición valores enteros de las imágenes que fueron añadidas de manera random a mi GridLayout.

```
 private int [] vector = new int[]{R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.green,R.drawable.yellow,R.drawable.red,R.drawable.purple,R.drawable.orange}; //Vector con imagenes
int matriz[][] = new int[8][8];
```

Unas vez armada la matriz 8x8, necesitaría saber, como haría para que el método "gemas" demi xml que va  a recibir una view, sepa la posición o las coordenadas del elemento de mi gridLayout que fue clickeado, es una duda que me esta matando

Comment: No sé mucho, pero mirando la documentación, supongo que puedes hacer uso de un evento mouse moved o dragged (que creo que es tu caso) y usar getPoint. Aquí la información completa: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías establecer la propiedad `Tag`a cada uno de los `ImageView` en el xml por ejemplo:

```
android:tag="1"
android:tag="2"
android:tag="3"
android:tag=".."
android:tag="64"
```

Y luego recuperar la posición en tu método gemas..

```
public void gemas(View view) {
        int posicion = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        if(posicion == 1) {
            ivUno.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
        } else if (posicion == 2)
            ivDos.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! Solucionado!

Comment: Un placer compañero. :)